# How to return Triple Count and its Contents using Sparql Query with Pagination

Tags: sparql, marklogic, marklogic-8

Is there any pre-defined method available with Marklogic 8 to return the total count of documents.

In case of Structured Query we are able to achieve it by doing this :

```
QueryManager queryMgr = client.newQueryManager();
SearchHandle resultsHandle = new SearchHandle();
queryMgr.search(query, resultsHandle, Long.parseLong(startIndex()));
ucbosDocuments.setTotalResults(resultsHandle.getTotalResults());
```

Is there any way we can achieve the same with any pre-defined functions in Sparql Query in marklogic 8 java client API. please do help me or point out on the direction to proceed !!!

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(*) WHERE {?s ?p ?o}`maybe?

Comment: No the above query does not work ! 

The below query works but need to accommodate document count and pagination with the below query.... 

SELECT ?s ?p ?o WHERE { ?s ?p ?o 
 FILTER regex(str(?p), "^linkedTo$", "i" )}

Comment: Marklogic supports full SPARQL 1.1, why should `SELECT (COUNT(*) as ?cnt) WHERE {?s ?p ?o}` not work then? Please try it with the var renaming in this comment.

Comment: @UninformedUser, it can return count, but not count + content together.